Windows Performance Monitor (PerfMon) not showing same value as corresponding WMI class
I have a PowerShell script to get all performance counters based on a list of WMI classes. However, the result of the PowerShell script is not consistent to what I see in Performance Monitor (PerfMon).
Here is an example PowerShell script that gives me both what PerfMon sees (via Get-Counter) and the result from WMI query:
$CounterName = "\xxxxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxx-updates"
$WMIQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx"

while ($true) {
    $counterValue = (Get-Counter -Counter $CounterName).CounterSamples.CookedValue

    $perfData = Get-WmiObject -Query $WMIQuery

    $wmiCounterValue = $perfData.xxxxxxxx-updates

    Clear-Host

    Write-Host "Performance Counter:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $counterValue

    Write-Host "`nWMI Counter:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $wmiCounterValue

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

Here is an example result:

Why are the result so much different when getting the data via WMI than using PerfMon or Get-Counter in PowerShell?
The "Performance Counter" value in the script is very consistent/even around 75-85 but the "WMI Counter" could be 0-200 during the same period of time.
We cannot use Get-Counter since it takes to much resources. If I would like to get 20 different performance counters using my script it would take approximately 1 second for each counter. Meaning the script would run around 20 seconds. Using WMI I can get the same amount in just 1-2 seconds.
The problem isn't getting counters using Get-Counter. The problem is that we're in a clustered environment which means that we would need to add -Credential to evaluate using a authenticated user and that process takes to long while using the Get-Counter method. This is why we prefer using the WMI class to SELECT * counters.
I assume that this is because PerfMon is showing an average and you get the same while using Get-Counter.
Have tried restarting winmgmt (Windows Management Instrumentation). Also tried running winmgmt /verifyrepository and it reports "WMI repository is consistent"
Or should I use the Raw Performance Counter Classes and do my own calculation?
How can I create a PowerShell script that uses Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM xxxxx" to get the same result as shown in PerfMon?

Try querying Win32_PerfRawData_* instead of Win32_PerfFormattedData_*. FWIW Get-Counter can fetch samples from multiple counters concurrently: Get-Counter -Counter $listOfCounterNames

I tried changing from Get-WmiObject to Get-CimInstance but same problem. Even added a timestamp to make sure they were fetched at the exact same time and used RawData but same problem. The numbers "243" was always the same, just the ones on red changed. Even if "Performance Counter at 2024-05-13-16:54:29" had the value of 320 the WMI remained at 243xxxxx. Example output:
`Performance Counter at 2024-05-13 16:54:29 :
320,128099109266
WMI Counter at 2024-05-13 16:54:29 :
243254244`
